# How can I add the first line in a text file to following lines until a condition is met then repeat?

Tags: python

I have this form of data in a text file.

UB25X

0060    4/22/16 -20.19

0060    3/17/15 -23.37

*UB25X

FJ39Y

0060    1/15/16 -27.34

0060    7/15/16 -23.10

*FJ39Y

---

I want to print this output:

UB25X   0060    4/22/16 -20.19

UB25X   0060    3/17/15 -23.37

FJ39Y   0060    1/15/16 -27.34

FJ39Y   0060    7/15/16 -23.10

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
input = '''UB25X
0060 4/22/16 -20.19
0060 3/17/15 -23.37
*UB25X
FJ39Y
0060 1/15/16 -27.34
0060 7/15/16 -23.10
*FJ39Y'''

l = input.split('\n')
tag = None
out = []

for item in l:
    if tag == item.replace('*',''):
        tag = None
    elif tag:
        out.append(tag + ' ' + item)
    else:
        tag = item

print out
# ['UB25X 0060 4/22/16 -20.19', 'UB25X 0060 3/17/15 -23.37', 'FJ39Y 0060 1/15/16 -27.34', 'FJ39Y 0060 7/15/16 -23.10']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, with txt file as first argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

file = sys.argv[1]
f = open(file, 'r')
prefix = None

for line in f:
    # continue if line is empty
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    # set prefix if it is not set and continue
    if prefix is None:
        prefix = line.strip()
        continue
    # unset prefix on given condition and continue
    if line.startswith('*' + prefix):
        prefix = None
        continue
    # if prefix is set and above does not apply print prefix plus line
    if prefix is not None:
        print(prefix + ' ' + line.strip())

f.close()
```

Comment: that almost has it, but the prefix didn't change after the first one. the line 4 prefix should change to FJ39Y

Comment: UB25X Gearbox 0060 4/22/16 -20.19

Comment: That does append the first line to the front of all of the following lines, but the appended line should change when the product changes. The first line is the name of an inventory item [NAME] and the following lines are inventory transactions until a record with an [* NAME].

Comment: Form your example above i assumed there is no space between * and NAME. If want it to work with a space between them change `'*'` to `'* '` in line 19.